# Kafka send nested json object

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, jackson

I am trying to create a basic Kafka project that will send nested JSON object but keep receiving only the root level field on the consumer.

```
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@ToString
public class UserCreate implements Serializable {

    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
    private final LocalDate createDate;

    private final List<Order> orders;

}
```

then Order class

```
@Builder
@Jacksonized
@ToString
public class Order implements Serializable {
   private final String name;
}
```

Producer Config:

```
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<String, UserCreate> transferProducerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> configProps = new HashMap<>();
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
    configProps.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(configProps);
}

@Bean
public KafkaTemplate<String, TransferRequest> transferKafkaTemplate() {
    return new KafkaTemplate<>(transferProducerFactory());
}
```

ConsumerConfig:

```
public ConsumerFactory<String, UserCreate> transferConsumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-group-id");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
        props,
        new StringDeserializer(),
        new JsonDeserializer<>(UserCreate.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UserCreate> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, UserCreate> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(transferConsumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
```

this setup ends with the following result:

```
Received message: UserCreate(createDate=2023-10-08, orders=null)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your list is nullable; the problem isn't directly related to the consumer. Kafka itself doesn't care what format your data is in. It stores bytes, so people generally use a binary data format rather than JSON since it's faster and takes less storage of the broker.

In any case, perhaps start debugging with printing the value of the producer before it's sent and just use `kafka-console-consumer` to look what your the broker is returning. If you see the list there, **then** worry about your deserializer and consumer config